# Accessing objects that are dependent objects in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need help figuring something out please. This is with Laravel 4.2 and it is from a blog and there is no way to contact the author or make comments..

http://vegibit.com/what-is-the-ioc-container-in-laravel/

Can someone give me an example of how to access the dependent objects in his example using object literal notation.

```
$myCar = App::make('Car');
```

So I would like to access the tread property of the Bridgestone object.

```
echo $myCar->Tire->Bridgestone()->tread;
```

This isn't working but this illustrates what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to print "Performance"

Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are protected, so try adding public functions that return the injected objects:

```
class Car {
    protected $tire;
    protected $engine;
    public function __construct(Tire $tire, Engine $engine) {
        $this->tire = $tire;
        $this->engine = $engine;
    }

    public function tire()
    {
        return $this->tire;
    }
}

class Tire {
    protected $bridgestone;
    public function __construct(Bridgestone $bridgestone) {
        $this->bridgestone = $bridgestone;
    }

    public function bridgestone()
    {
        return $this->bridgestone;
    }
}
```

Your call for the tread would then be:

```
echo $car->tire()->bridgestone()->tread;
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. That was the explanation I needed. It makes sense now.